# With JQueryUI Draggable, how to select draggable element when draggables are layered

Tags: html, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using JQueryUI draggable and would like to choose which draggable element gets dragged when multiple are stacked on each other (one on top of the other).

Should I do something within the "start" method?

```js
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    // Is there a way I can select to drag #e2:
    // so I can use program logic to select which draggable I want to get dragged
  }
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="draggable" id="e1" style="background-color: red">1</div>
<div class="draggable" id="e2" style="background-color: green">2</div>
<div class="draggable" id="e3" style="background-color: blue">3</div>
```

I'm also pasting a jsFiddle for simpler testing:
[Jquery UI stacked (layered) draggables](http://jsfiddle.net/5eLbLfyp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to propagate the drag or click event after the first (on top) layer receive it so I thought of another way:

when you click on two or more layers it shows a list of the divs under the mouse then you choose from them the required div and a z-index higher than the others is given to it and you can easily move it (as it's on top now )
here is a demo of this idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/axzg0oqz/1/

```
$('.draggable').draggable().click(function(e) {
  var point = {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY
  };

  var all = $($(this).parent().children());
  var selected = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length - 1; i++) {
    if (included(point, all[i])) {
      selected.push(all[i]);
    }
  }

  if (selected.length > 1)
    createList(selected, point);
});
```

hope it helps.